# Enter Key press creating extra "1"

Tags: c#, winforms, calculator

I'm currently trying to program a simple Winforms calculator, and am working on assigning the NumPad keys to the form buttons. Every button I've assigned so far works correctly, except the Enter button. No matter the expression entered, when the physical enter key is pressed it adds a separate "1" to the end of the answer [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPiqx.png). It works correctly when just the form button is pressed. 
Does anybody know why this is, or can help me out some?
I also realize some of my code is not needed, so let me off easy, I'm a mere student!

Here's the key detection code and the relevant methods it leads into:

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            enterButton.PerformClick();
        }
        if (keyData == Keys.NumPad0)
        {
            button10.PerformClick();
        }
        if (keyData == Keys.NumPad1)
        {
            button1.PerformClick();
        }
        if (keyData == Keys.NumPad2)
        {
            button2.PerformClick();
        }
        if (keyData == Keys.NumPad3)
        {
            button3.PerformClick();
        }
        if (keyData == Keys.NumPad4)
        {
            button4.PerformClick();
        }
        if (keyData == Keys.NumPad5)
        {
            button5.PerformClick();
        }
        if (keyData == Keys.NumPad6)
        {
            button6.PerformClick();
        }
        if (keyData == Keys.NumPad7)
        {
            button7.PerformClick();
        }
        if (keyData == Keys.NumPad8)
        {
            button8.PerformClick();
        }
        if (keyData == Keys.NumPad9)
        {
            button9.PerformClick();
        }
        if (keyData == Keys.Add)
        {
            addButton.PerformClick();
        }
        if (keyData == Keys.Subtract)
        {
            minusButton.PerformClick();
        }
        if (keyData == Keys.Multiply)
        {
            timesButton.PerformClick();
        }
        if (keyData == Keys.Divide)
        {
            divideButton.PerformClick();
        }
    }
    private void enterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operIsDone = true; //triggers final calculation
        MainCalc();
    }
    private void MainCalc()
    {
        do
        {
            if (operation == '+')
            {
                operand = stringToInt(inputString);
                inputString = cleared;
                ansCache += operand;
                operand = 0;
                break;
            }
            if (operation == '-')
            {
                if (minusButton.Tag.Equals("1"))
                {
                    operand = stringToInt(inputString);
                    inputString = cleared;
                    ansCache += operand;
                    minusButton.Tag = "2";
                    break;
                }
                else if (minusButton.Tag.Equals("2"))
                {
                    operand = stringToInt(inputString);
                    inputString = cleared;
                    ansCache -= operand;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(operation == '*')
            {
                if (timesButton.Tag.Equals("1"))
                {
                    operand = stringToInt(inputString);
                    inputString = cleared;
                    ansCache += operand;
                    timesButton.Tag = "2";
                    break;
                }
                else if (timesButton.Tag.Equals("2"))
                {
                    operand = stringToInt(inputString);
                    inputString = cleared;
                    ansCache *= operand;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(operation == '/')
            {
                if (divideButton.Tag.Equals("1"))
                {
                    operand = stringToInt(inputString);
                    inputString = cleared;
                    ansCache += operand;
                    divideButton.Tag = "2";
                    break;
                }
                else if (divideButton.Tag.Equals("2"))
                {
                    operand = stringToInt(inputString);
                    inputString = cleared;
                    if (operand != 0)
                    {
                        ansCache /= operand;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        statusLabel.Text = "Cannot Divide By Zero!";
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if(operIsDone) { break; }
        }
        while (calc);

        if (operIsDone)
        {
            statusLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(ansCache) + "";
            statusText = statusLabel.Text;
        }
```

Comment: Can you upload the entire ProcessCmdKey i have a feeling something is going on in there. Or a link to your git repo where this code is housed

Comment: My educated guess is that the button for 1 is set up as the AcceptButton for the form, which is probably causing the event to be fired twice.

Comment: I would try adding a System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine to the beginning of main calc and i would suspect that the 1 key is setup as an else statement or something of that nature thats causing it to call maincalc as well

Comment: @willthiswork89 I uploaded the rest of ProcessCmdKey, but the only problem I'm having is the extra 1 added by the enter key. The 1 is not saved to the ansCache variable, or any other. It appears at the end after the label text is set to answer of the expression.

Comment: @Juan There is no AcceptButton set for the form.

Comment: Do you have this in a git repository? I dont think the problem is within the code you have given and the problem is actually in an ommissioned piece of code. I would like to personally run this and take a look im sure its something silly.

Comment: My guess is that you have a tab index of zero on that "1" button.  When your calculation is done, you are doing something (beyond the code you show here or in the way the form is built) that returns focus to the default first button on the form and it is getting seen as a click on the 1.  Try setting the tab index of that "1" button to -1.  It should start adding maybe "2" to the end of the answer.

Comment: The ProcessCmdKey still seems incomplete.

Comment: @willthiswork89 I don't have a repo for this, but I'd be more than happy to set one up if that helps.

Comment: yes, please if possible.

Comment: @AgapwIesu It won't allow me to change the TabIndex to a negative, but when I set the TabIndex for Button1 to 0, it will put a 2 at the end. Same thing for button2, and so forth.

Comment: Sorry, the -1 is from dealing with web-apps where -1 means the control gets taken out of the tab order of the form.  So, look at my answer.  Basically your Enter key is getting processed as a cmd key **and** a click on whatever button has focus.  This is the typical behavior of the enter key.

Comment: You have to post the code that duplicates the problem for us.  Your ProcessCmdKey override should be showing a "not all code paths return a value" error.

Comment: Unrelated, look into `switch` statements.  They'll make your code a lot easier to read (and in this case, cut back on the number of lines by a significant amount)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your "1" button has focus.  When your calculation is done, the enter key is then seen as a click on the 1.  It is standard behavior for the enter key to be interpreted as a click on the button that has focus.  Try setting the tab index of that "1" button to 0.  It should start adding maybe "2" to the end of the answer.

If that is the case, what I would do, is in ProcessCmdKey, the only thing I would do for the enter key is to shift focus to the calculator's "enter" button.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        enterButton.Focus();
    }
```

The regular behavior of the keyboard enter key will take care of doing the click on that key, so you don't have to do a PerformClick.

And, set your enter button as the "Accept" button on your form.  This means that whenever the user presses "Enter" on their keyboard, your "Enter" button's click event will get fired.  Basically, pressing the "Enter" button on the user's physical keyboard will be just like clicking on your calculator's "Enter" button.

Basically, your problem, I figure, is that your pressing the Enter button is (after calculating the answer) is also being seen as a press on whatever button has focus, which causes the "1" button's click event handler to also get performed, which calls button1.PerformClick(), and "1" gets added to what is in your calculator's "display screen".

Comment: Ah good thought here. I would go one further and say it might be easier to process the enter command and then return false on the processCmdKey to ignore it entirely since the focus may cause unintended results.

Comment: @willthiswork89 - yes, you are right.  I did not like my answer entirely either, and not knowing the rest of his code, it is hard to come up with something, but I think I did - use the "AcceptButton" behavior of a form - set that "Enter" button of his form to be the "AcceptButton", and just not do anything with it as a command key.  I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @agapwlesu Thanks! That looks to be what is causing the problem. So would I just set the focus to the enter button, and then do a PerformClick() after that?

Comment: No, take out the code in ProcessCmdKey that processes that enter button.  So it is never processed as a command key.  Then go to the form's properties and set the AcceptButton to be your calculator's "Enter" button.

Comment: @AgapwIesu Ok, that works well in combination with the other answer, but it isn't ideal as I would like to use tab to get to all the buttons. When the AcceptButton is set to the calculator's enterButton and all TabStop properties are set to true, it just sends whatever button has focus at that time. edit: Exactly what you were mentioning below on the 2nd answer.

Comment: In that case, you could add code in your ProcessCmdKey that process the user's enter key as a cmd key that just changes the focus to your calculator's enter key.  And do not disable the buttons out of the tab order.  That should get you what you want, I think.  I am changing my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Like Agapwlesu mentioned, it could be the fact that your number 1 button is focused and that enter is pressing the 1 button as well as doing the function you intended. My solution however, is a little different.

Under the properties for each button you should find one labeled `Tab Stop`. If you set that equal to `false` for each of your buttons, they will no longer be able to be focused, and therefore should keep them from being pressed when you hit enter.

Comment: I don't like this because it still leaves the enter behavior doing who knows what depending on what has focus.  Better to change the enter behavior to be a click on the calculator's "enter" button by setting it as the form's accept button.

Comment: This works for my purposes right now, I was only trying to program this to see how it would work, so thanks all for the help. I just setup a GitHub account, check it out here: https://github.com/jpdixon1/FullCalcProgram

Comment: Definitely agree with you on that Agapwlesu. It's not a perfect solution, but for what it's worth it should get the job done.